# docker: Error creating container: 400 Client Error: Bad Request (\"invalid reference format\")"

Tags: docker, ansible, ansible-awx

While trying to build an awx image (Ansible works) for ppc64le, the following comes up:

```
TASK [image_build : Build AWX distribution using container] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Error creating container: 400 Client Error: Bad Request (\"invalid reference format\")"}
        to retry, use: --limit @/root/awx/installer/install.retry

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=10   changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

How can I see what really happens in the background? Any verbose docker logs that I can look at? The message itself is somewhat useless to me. I already set Ansible to verbose but this also was of no help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker image names can only consist of lowercase (a-z) characters. 
Either you are giving a un-supported image name or the variable(or paths) passed to the buid(or the container) cannot be resolved.

To enable debug logs, add "--debug" to docker daemon (/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/docker.service for systemd based linux env)

For reference: https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/#configure-the-docker-daemon